# Bump Mapping in OpenGL and GLSL

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, bump-mapping

I'm trying to implement bump mapping on a cube using OpenGL and GLSL. However, when I rotate my cube around, only the left-facing square and right-facing square appear (that is, in the negative x and positive x direction), the other four faces of the cube (top, bottom, front, back) are black. Here is an example:

[image]

My mesh class consists of an indexList and vertexList (the Vertex class contains x, y, z, etc). I'm using [this](http://pastebin.com/fmYbD5Qs) simple cube.ply model, which contains s,t texture coordinates. Borrowing from [this example](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/2011/03/normal-mapping-tutorial.html), I calculate the tangent vectors as follows:

```
void Mesh::computeTangents() {

        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_indexList.size(); i += 3) {

            Vertex v1 = m_vertexList[m_indexList[i]];
            Vertex v2 = m_vertexList[m_indexList[i+1]];
            Vertex v3 = m_vertexList[m_indexList[i+2]];

            glm::vec3 pos1 = glm::vec3(v1.getX(), v1.getY(), v1.getZ());
            glm::vec3 pos2 = glm::vec3(v2.getX(), v2.getY(), v2.getZ());
            glm::vec3 pos3 = glm::vec3(v3.getX(), v3.getY(), v3.getZ());
            glm::vec2 tex1 = glm::vec2(v1.getS(), v1.getT());
            glm::vec2 tex2 = glm::vec2(v2.getS(), v2.getT());
            glm::vec2 tex3 = glm::vec2(v3.getS(), v3.getT());

            glm::vec3 edge1 = glm::normalize(pos2 - pos1);
            glm::vec3 edge2 = glm::normalize(pos3 - pos1);

            glm::vec2 texEdge1 = glm::normalize(tex2 - tex1);
            glm::vec2 texEdge2 = glm::normalize(tex3 - tex1);

            float det = (texEdge1.x * texEdge2.y) - (texEdge1.y * texEdge2.x);

            glm::vec3 tangent;

            if(fabsf(det) < 1e-6f) {
                tangent.x = 1.0;
                tangent.y = 0.0;
                tangent.z = 0.0;
            }
            else {
                det = 1.0 / det;

                tangent.x = (texEdge2.y * edge1.x - texEdge1.y * edge2.x) * det;
                tangent.y = (texEdge2.y * edge1.y - texEdge1.y * edge2.y) * det;
                tangent.z = (texEdge2.y * edge1.z - texEdge1.y * edge2.z) * det;

                glm::normalize(tangent);
            }

            m_vertexList[m_indexList[i]].setTanX(tangent.x);
            m_vertexList[m_indexList[i]].setTanY(tangent.y);
            m_vertexList[m_indexList[i]].setTanZ(tangent.z);
            m_vertexList[m_indexList[i+1]].setTanX(tangent.x);
            m_vertexList[m_indexList[i+1]].setTanY(tangent.y);
            m_vertexList[m_indexList[i+1]].setTanZ(tangent.z);
            m_vertexList[m_indexList[i+2]].setTanX(tangent.x);
            m_vertexList[m_indexList[i+2]].setTanY(tangent.y);
            m_vertexList[m_indexList[i+2]].setTanZ(tangent.z);
        }
    }
```

If I output the values of the tangent vector for each triangle, I get these values:
1, 0, 0
1, 0, 0
0, 0, -1
0, 0, -1
0, 0, 1
0, 0, 1
-1, 0, 0
-1, 0, 0,
1, 0, 0
1, 0, 0
1, 0, 0
1, 0, 0

If these are correct, then the problem is likely in the shader. My shader is as follows (mostly taken from a book):

vert:

```
attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
attribute vec3 vertexNormal;
attribute vec2 vertexTexture;
attribute vec3 vertexTangent;

varying vec2 texCoord;
varying vec3 viewDirection;
varying vec3 lightDirection;

uniform vec3 diffuseColor;
uniform float shininess;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 MVP; // modelview projection

void main() {
    vec4 eyePosition = modelViewMatrix * vertexPosition;
    vec3 N = normalize(vec3(normalMatrix * vec4(vertexNormal, 1.0)));
    vec3 T = normalize(vec3(normalMatrix * vec4(vertexTangent, 1.0)));
    vec3 B = normalize(cross(N, T));

    vec3 v;
    v.x = dot(lightPosition.xyz, T);
    v.y = dot(lightPosition.xyz, B);
    v.z = dot(lightPosition.xyz, N);
    lightDirection = normalize(v);

    v.x = dot(eyePosition.xyz, T);
    v.y = dot(eyePosition.xyz, B);
    v.z = dot(eyePosition.xyz, N);
    viewDirection = normalize(v);

    texCoord = vertexTexture;
    gl_Position = MVP * vertexPosition;
}
```

Frag:

```
varying vec2 texCoord;
varying vec3 viewDirection;
varying vec3 lightDirection;

uniform vec3 diffuseColor;
uniform float shininess;

void main() {

    float bumpDensity = 16.0;
    float bumpSize = 0.15;

    vec2 c = bumpDensity * texCoord;
    vec2 p = fract(c) - vec2(0.5);

    float d, f;
    d = dot(p, p);
    f = 1.0 / sqrt(d + 1.0);

    if (d >= bumpSize) {
        p = vec2(0.0);
        f = 1.0;
    }

    vec3 normalDelta = vec3(p.x, p.y, 1.0) * f;
    vec3 litColor = diffuseColor * max(dot(normalDelta, lightDirection), 0.0);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(lightDirection, normalDelta);
    float spec = max(dot(viewDirection, reflectDir), 0.0);
    spec *= shininess;
    litColor = min(litColor + spec, vec3(1.0));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(litColor, 1.0);
 }
```

Edit: Changed background to more clearly see the black faces. Also, I incorrectly noted which faces were actually appearing before.

Edit 2: I'm finding that the value of max(dot(normalDelta, lightDirection), 0.0) in the fragment shader returns 0 for those faces. However, I still don't know why.

Edit 3: Well, the problem turned out to be that I was passing the wrong index of the tangent vectors in my Vertex class. That is, I had 10 in this line instead of 9:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(v3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)(sizeof( float ) * 9));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem is that any face with a normal on the xz-plane isn't rendering properly, i.e. the ones that *are* rendering properly are the ones with normals along the y-axis (top and bottom faces).

And your list of tangents:

```
 1, 0,  0
 1, 0,  0
 0, 0, -1
 0, 0, -1
 0, 0,  1
 0, 0,  1
-1, 0,  0
-1, 0,  0
 1, 0,  0
 1, 0,  0
 1, 0,  0
 1, 0,  0
```

Are all either along the x or z axes. So what I'm *guessing* might be happening is that your normals and tangents are pointing in the same (or opposite) directions, in which case this line in your vertex shader:

```
vec3 B = normalize(cross(N, T));
```

is going to result in vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), which can't be normalized.

My recommendation is to try manually giving the x and z faces tangents along the y-axis, see if that makes a difference. If it helps, then you know that the problem is with your computation of the tangents.

If it doesn't help, you can troubleshoot by outputting values from the fragment shader as on-screen colours. Try displaying the viewDirection, lightDirection, normalDelta, reflectDir, and anything else you can think of to see which variable is causing the blackness.

Bonus: Switch the glClear color to something other than black? So that it doesn't look like a face floating in space.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Actually, after looking at it again, I incorrectly saw which faces actually appear. It turns out it is the left face and right face which appear. Also, I double-checked the tangent values as you suggested, and I believe they are correct. For each triangle I manually checked wolfram alpha for the normal X tangent vector, and in each case it gives a proper bitangent vector which makes a complete coordinate system.  So, I'm guessing (and hoping) I can narrow down the problem into the shader.

Comment: Check my Edit 3. Although it is impractical to post my whole code (which may contain such bugs as I noted), your suggestions helped me debug and double-check everything associated with the tangent vectors. Thanks!